# Taylor polynomial 3rd degree in 3 variables?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have to calculate taylor polynomial 3rd degree in 3 variables for this function in point (0,0,0):

$f\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(x^{2}+z \right)\cdot e^{xz+y^{2} }    $

I dont know how to expand formula for this. I found some general formulas but I just got lost when I started. Could someone write that formula?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the general *Taylor's formula*:
$$f(x,y,z)=f(0,0,0)+\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Bigr)^{\rlap k}\cdot f \;{(0,0,0)}+o\bigl(\lVert(x,y,z)\rVert^n\bigr).$$

First, as $x^2+z$ is its own Taylor's polynomial, it is enough to expand $\mathrm e^{xz+y2}$ at order $2$.

Second, as the argument of the exponential is homogeneous of degree $2$, we only need to expand $\mathrm e^u$ at order $1$. So 
\begin{align*}(x^{2}+z)\,\mathrm e^{xz+y^{2}}&=(x^2+z)(1+xz+y^2+o\bigl(\lVert(x,y,z)\rVert^2\bigr)\\&=
z+x^2+xz^2+y^2z+ x^3z+x^2z^2+(x^2+z)o\bigl(\lVert(x,y,z)\rVert^2\bigr)\\
&=z+x^2+xz^2+y^2z+o\bigl(\lVert(x,y,z)\rVert^3\bigr).
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is x^2+z its own Taylor's polynomial? Thanks.

Comment: Any polynomial is its own Taylor's polynomial at the origin (at order $\ge$ degree of the polynomial) because it is its own approximation, and Taylor's polynomial is unique. For one variable polynomials, it's well known Taylor's formula is an exact formula. –

Comment: Is it possible from this solution to get Hessian matrix and gradient?

Answer (score 1):

I will not calculate it. I will just write a formula.

Let $T_f^{(3)} (x)$ denote the Taylor polynomial of order 3 in $(0,0,0)$. For convenience, let us denote $x=x_1 , y=x_2, z=x_3$. Then

\begin{align*}
T^3 f(x) & = f(0,0,0)+\sum_{k=1}^{3} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} (0,0,0)(x_i -0)\\
&\phantom{=..}+\frac{1}{2!}\sum_{i,j=1}^3 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(0,0,0)(x_i-0)(x_j-0)\\
&\phantom{=..}+\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{i,j,k=1}^3 \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j\partial x_k}(0,0,0)(x_i-0)(x_j-0)(x_k-0)
\end{align*}

To think this formula, recall the one-dimensional one. This multi-dimensional one is proved by using one-dimensional Tayler expansion and chain rule.

Proof gives a way to calculate something in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never heard of the multivariable Taylor formula, you can anyway solve as follows.

First consider $y,z$ as parameters and find the Taylor development around $x=0$:

$$f(x)=(x^2+z)e^{xy+y^2},\\
f'(x)=(2x+y(x^2+z))e^{xy+y^2},\\
f''(x)=(y^2(x^2+z)+4xy+2)e^{xy+y^2},\\
f'''(x)=((x^2+z)y^3+6xy^2+6y)e^{xy+y^2}.$$

Then

$$f_{yz}(0)=ze^{y^2},\\
f'_{yz}(0)=yze^{y^2},\\
f''_{yz}(0)=(y^2z+2)e^{y^2},\\
f'''_{yz}(0)=(zy^3+6y)e^{y^2}.$$

This allows you to write

$$f_{yz}(x)=ze^{y^2}+yze^{y^2}x+(y^2z+2)e^{y^2}\frac{x^2}2+(zy^3+6y)e^{y^2}\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

Now you can repeat the process with $y$ as a variable and $x,z$ as two parameters, giving

$$ze^{y^2}=z+zy^2+z\frac{y^4}2+\cdots,\\
yze^{y^2}x=zyx+zy^3x+\cdots\\\cdots$$

As it turns out, after this step all transcendental functions of $z$ have disappeared and you end-up with the requested third degree polynomial.